# How to catch the b-form-input event that deletes the input value

Tags: typescript, forms, vue.js, events, bootstrap-vue

I have tried myself and searched extensively to find out how to catch the event that is triggered when you click `x` icon in a b-form-input of the type 'search':

[image: Screenshot of b-form-input of search type]

template:

```
<b-form-input
    id="filter-input"
    type="search"
    v-model="filter"
    @keydown.enter="onFilterChange(filter)"
    @emptied.native="resetFilter(emptiedEvent)"
/>
```

script:

```
public resetFilter(event: any) {
  console.log("todo: resetFilter");
}
```

I tried different event handlers: `@emptied`, `@reset`, `@close`, `@cancel`, `@drop`... None of them seem to fire.
What am I missing? Is there none in Bootstrap Vue, possibly? The [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input) didn't help.
Is the only way to use the standard `@change` event (checking if the input value was emptied)?

Comment: the delete icon ...is that a custom one that you created

Comment: @Amaarrockz no I did not, this I would have mentioned. have a look at the docs, it is displayed for all search inputs - it is an html5 feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The non-standard `search` event that you shouldn't use**

The HTML5 [`search` input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search) does emit a **non-standard** [`search` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/search_event) when you click the `x` but unfortunately it also emits that when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so you will have to check the text value in the handler to determine if the input was cleared.

**Use the `input` or `change` event instead**

But I would recommend using `input` or `change` instead if that works for your purposes, because of this caveat from the MDN docs:

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

```html
<b-form-input
    id="filter-input"
    type="search"
    v-model="filter"
    @keydown.enter="onFilterChange(filter)"
    @search="resetFilter"
/>
```

```js
resetFilter() {
  if(!this.filter) {
    console.log('search cleared')
  }
}
```

Be aware that this will also trigger when you press enter on an empty input.

Comment: @Dan Thanks but I can't seem to find info specifically on the 'search' event, there. It only declares the two events: 'change' and 'input'. Sorry..

Comment: Try this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/search_event

Comment: Also found it :-D "Current UA implementations of <input type="search"> have an additional control to clear the field. Using this control also fires the search event. In that case the value of the <input> element will be the empty string."  [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/search_event)